# Memory efficient parallelization of loop using MPI and mpi4py

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi, shared-memory, mpi4py

I am new to parallel programming and MPI, and I am stuck on this possibly easy problem ...

I am trying to write a code which evolve a system of N gravitationally interacting particles forward in time. This is quite easy using a naive algorithm, which is what I have done. But now I want to parallelize my code. Specifically I am writing in Python using mpi4py. A simplified (and heavily optimizable, but that is not the point), non-parallel implementation would look something like this:

```
# pos and vel are arrays storing the positions and velocities of all particles
dt = 0.01  # The time step
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if i == j:
            continue
        # Calculate force between i'th and j'th particle
        r = pos[j] - pos[i]
        force -= r/norm(r)**3
        # Update velocity
        vel[i] -= dt*force
# Now use vel to update pos ...
```

How do I go about parallelizing this algorithm? Since the number of particles `N` could be very large, I want to store `pos` and `vel` only on the root process, to save memory. My initial thought was to parallelize the `i`-loop, but every process still needs access to `pos` and `vel` in their entirety! That is, a Scatter/Gather scheme is not helpful.

Am I forced to have a copy of `pos` and `vel` in memory for every process, or are there some way out of this?
A simple way out would be to share the memory containing `pos` and `vel` across all processes, without making duplicates. I do not know if this is possible with MPI (and specifically mpi4py).

Any help would be gratefully accepted!

Comment: multiprocessing, shared memory - two keywords that you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the usual way to go about this is using domain decomposition. You divide the particles up into as many domains as you like (usually one per MPI process or one per core if you're doing multithreading). Then you use ghost regions and MPI communication to define the interactions between different domains.

Giving you a bigger answer than that is pretty involved so I'd encourage you to go check out those ideas and come back with specific problems.